# How to deal with 'residues are not finite in the initial point' when I use scipy.optimize?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, data-science, non-linear-regression

I am new to python and I want to execute a non-linear regression with the use of scipy.optimize.

I followed the introduction of scipy documentation and this is a part of my code.

I have organized the S_ADV, volatility and POV as several numpy arrays and they are the observations in my regression. With MI, I want to get the parameters x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3] by this regression.

```
def model(x,S_ADV,volatility,POV):
    return x[0] * x[1] * S_ADV ** x[2] * volatility ** x[3] * POV + (1-x[0]) * x[1] * S_ADV ** x[2]  * volatility ** x[3]


def fun(x,S_ADV,volatility,POV,MI):
    return model(x,S_ADV,volatility,POV) - MI

def jac(x,S_ADV,volatility,POV,MI):
    JAC = np.empty((S_ADV.size, x.size))
    JAC[:,0] = x[1] * S_ADV ** x[2] * volatility ** x[3] * POV - x[1] * S_ADV ** x[2]  * volatility ** x[3]
    JAC[:,1] = x[0]* S_ADV ** x[2] * volatility ** x[3] * POV + (1-x[0]) * S_ADV ** x[2]  * volatility ** x[3]
    JAC[:,2] = x[0] * x[1] * S_ADV ** x[2] * math.log(math.e,S_ADV) * volatility ** x[3] * POV + (1-x[0]) * x[1] * S_ADV ** x[2] * math.log(math.e,S_ADV) * volatility ** x[3]
    JAC[:,3] = x[0] * x[1] * S_ADV ** x[2] * volatility ** x[3]  * math.log(math.e,volatility) * POV + (1-x[0]) * x[1] * S_ADV ** x[2]  * volatility ** x[3] * math.log(math.e,volatility)
    return jac
x0 = np.array([7.00,0.7,0.2,1.00,1.00])


res = least_squares(fun, x0, jac = jac, args = (S_ADV,volatility,POV,MI))
```

Is there any mistakes in my code and how to deal with this problem?

```
ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point.
```

Answer (score 0):

Print the value of `fun` at x0, it should be floating-point number.

Comment: Yes. That's [-0.00038389 -0.01979665 -0.01266975 ... -0.00269337  0.00836692
 -0.00611874]. But I still don't know what caused the problem.

Comment: I'd walk the call chain with `import pdb; pdb.pm()` then.